# Gerar todos os caminhos possíveis

Tags: c, funções

Em um exercício, preciso imprimir, em um arquivo, todas as possibilidades de trajetória entre um número `N` de cidades, sendo que cada cidade é representada por coordenadas `x` e `y` e que a última cidade deve ser a primeira (Todas as cidades devem ser testadas como ponto de partida). O arquivo de saida deve ser da seguinte maneira:

```
(ax,ay)    (bx,by)    (cx,cy)    ...    (ax,ay)
(ax,ay)    (cx,cy)    (bx,by)    ...    (ax,ay)
(bx,by)    (ax,ay)    (cx,cy)    ...    (bx,by)
```

Onde cada linha do arquivo exibe uma trajetória possível e as cidades sendo representadas por suas coordenadas entre parênteses.

Estou com um pouco de dificuldade ao elaborar o raciocínio da função que irá gerar as possibilidades. Esse problema pode ser considerado como um problema de permutação?

Há pouco tempo implementei duas funções que geram permutações de uma sequência, como pode ser visto abaixo:

```
void Troca(char *x, char *y)
{
    char aux;
    aux = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = aux;
}

void Permuta(char *sequencia, int inicio, int termino)
{
    int j;
    if(inicio == termino)
        printf("%s\n", sequencia);
    else
    {
        for(j = inicio; j <= termino; j++)
        {
            Troca((sequencia+inicio), (sequencia+j));
            Permuta(sequencia, inicio+1, termino);
            Troca((sequencia+inicio), (sequencia+j));
        }
    }
}
```

Caso esse problema possa ser encarado como um problema de permutação, eu posso utilizar dessas funções e desenvolver em cima delas? Eu tentei, porém não consegui usar a struct de `Cidade` dentro delas.

Cheguei a pensar em criar uma sequência que vai de 1 até `N` e considerar como se fossem os índices do meu vetor `*Cidades`, mas também não consegui implementar.

Gostaria de saber se as ideias que propus são cabíveis e/ou se há alguma outra forma melhor de se desenvolver o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim. Sua ideia funciona nesse caso. O seu código pode ser escrito assim:

```
void Permuta(struct cidade *sequencia, int inicio, int termino)
{
    int j;
    if(inicio == termino) {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            printf("(%d,%d)\t", sequencia[i].x, sequencia[i].y);
        }
        printf("(%d %d)\n", sequencia[0].x, sequencia[0].y);
    }
    else
    {
        for(j = inicio; j <= termino; j++) {
            Troca((sequencia+inicio), (sequencia+j));
            Permuta(sequencia, inicio+1, termino);
            Troca((sequencia+inicio), (sequencia+j));
        }
    }
}
```

Não acho que tenha como fazer melhor que isso com essa descrição do problema, porque a sua saída vai ter a ordem de um fatorial. Isto é, seu algoritmo vai ter que imprimir uma saída de tamanho N um numero N! de vezes.